# white space between listview Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview that is connected to sqlserver but the columns of listview are shown without any white space in-between. I want to add a feature like cellpadding in table to my Listview.
My code :

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="DarkhastId" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupItemCount="2">

            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    DarkhastId:
                    <asp:Label ID="DarkhastIdLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("DarkhastId") %>' />
                    <br />
                    shakhs:
                    <asp:Label ID="shakhsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("shakhs") %>' />
                    <br />
                    nam:
                    <asp:Label ID="namLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nam") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Idgharardad:
                    <asp:Label ID="IdgharardadLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Idgharardad") %>' />
                    <br />
                    elat:
                    <asp:Label ID="elatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("elat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    hamrah:
                    <asp:Label ID="hamrahLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hamrah") %>' />
                    <br />
                    sabet:
                    <asp:Label ID="sabetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sabet") %>' />
                    <br />
                    vaziat:
                    <asp:Label ID="vaziatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vaziat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    karshenas:
                    <asp:Label ID="karshenasLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("karshenas") %>' />
                    <br />
                    tarikh:
                    <asp:Label ID="tarikhLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tarikh") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                        Text="Delete" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    DarkhastId:
                    <asp:Label ID="DarkhastIdLabel1" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("DarkhastId") %>' />
                    <br />
                    shakhs:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="shakhsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shakhs") %>' />
                    <br />
                    nam:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="namTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nam") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Idgharardad:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="IdgharardadTextBox" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("Idgharardad") %>' />
                    <br />
                    elat:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="elatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("elat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    hamrah:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="hamrahTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hamrah") %>' />
                    <br />
                    sabet:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="sabetTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sabet") %>' />
                    <br />
                    vaziat:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="vaziatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vaziat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    karshenas:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="karshenasTextBox" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("karshenas") %>' />
                    <br />
                    tarikh:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tarikhTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tarikh") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                        Text="Update" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                        Text="Cancel" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <EmptyItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" />
            </EmptyItemTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    shakhs:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="shakhsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shakhs") %>' />
                    <br />
                    nam:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="namTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nam") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Idgharardad:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="IdgharardadTextBox" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("Idgharardad") %>' />
                    <br />
                    elat:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="elatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("elat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    hamrah:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="hamrahTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hamrah") %>' />
                    <br />
                    sabet:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="sabetTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sabet") %>' />
                    <br />
                    vaziat:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="vaziatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vaziat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    karshenas:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="karshenasTextBox" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("karshenas") %>' />
                    <br />
                    tarikh:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tarikhTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tarikh") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                        Text="Insert" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                        Text="Clear" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    DarkhastId:
                    <asp:Label ID="DarkhastIdLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("DarkhastId") %>' />
                    <br />
                    shakhs:
                    <asp:Label ID="shakhsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("shakhs") %>' />
                    <br />
                    nam:
                    <asp:Label ID="namLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nam") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Idgharardad:
                    <asp:Label ID="IdgharardadLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Idgharardad") %>' />
                    <br />
                    elat:
                    <asp:Label ID="elatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("elat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    hamrah:
                    <asp:Label ID="hamrahLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hamrah") %>' />
                    <br />
                    sabet:
                    <asp:Label ID="sabetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sabet") %>' />
                    <br />
                    vaziat:
                    <asp:Label ID="vaziatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vaziat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    karshenas:
                    <asp:Label ID="karshenasLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("karshenas") %>' />
                    <br />
                    tarikh:
                    <asp:Label ID="tarikhLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tarikh") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                        Text="Delete" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server">
                            <table ID="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server" style="">
                            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="12">
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                                        ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                </Fields>
                            </asp:DataPager>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    DarkhastId:
                    <asp:Label ID="DarkhastIdLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("DarkhastId") %>' />
                    <br />
                    shakhs:
                    <asp:Label ID="shakhsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("shakhs") %>' />
                    <br />
                    nam:
                    <asp:Label ID="namLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nam") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Idgharardad:
                    <asp:Label ID="IdgharardadLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Idgharardad") %>' />
                    <br />
                    elat:
                    <asp:Label ID="elatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("elat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    hamrah:
                    <asp:Label ID="hamrahLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hamrah") %>' />
                    <br />
                    sabet:
                    <asp:Label ID="sabetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sabet") %>' />
                    <br />
                    vaziat:
                    <asp:Label ID="vaziatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("vaziat") %>' />
                    <br />
                    karshenas:
                    <asp:Label ID="karshenasLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("karshenas") %>' />
                    <br />
                    tarikh:
                    <asp:Label ID="tarikhLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tarikh") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                        Text="Delete" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:akhbarrrConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [darkhastezam] WHERE [DarkhastId] = @DarkhastId" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [darkhastezam] ([shakhs], [nam], [Idgharardad], [elat], [hamrah], [sabet], [vaziat], [karshenas], [tarikh]) VALUES (@shakhs, @nam, @Idgharardad, @elat, @hamrah, @sabet, @vaziat, @karshenas, @tarikh)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [darkhastezam]" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [darkhastezam] SET [shakhs] = @shakhs, [nam] = @nam, [Idgharardad] = @Idgharardad, [elat] = @elat, [hamrah] = @hamrah, [sabet] = @sabet, [vaziat] = @vaziat, [karshenas] = @karshenas, [tarikh] = @tarikh WHERE [DarkhastId] = @DarkhastId">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DarkhastId" Type="Decimal" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="shakhs" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="nam" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Idgharardad" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="elat" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="hamrah" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="sabet" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="vaziat" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="karshenas" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="tarikh" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="shakhs" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="nam" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Idgharardad" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="elat" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="hamrah" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="sabet" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="vaziat" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="karshenas" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="tarikh" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DarkhastId" Type="Decimal" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add CssClass to all table tags

```
<table class="test" ...
```

1. Create inline style (or external). You can change the styling to margin or padding-top / padding-bottom that fits your needs.

   table.test td { 
        padding: 3px;
    }

Comment: I test it. after adding test class in all of asp tags, all asp controls are stretched!

Comment: OK. now that we know this method worked, what do you mean by stretched? You add the class only to the listview items that need padding, correct? Try padding-top: 3px;

Comment: I add it to all of asp tags in list view and now buttons and textboxes in listview have 15 px padding in themselves not environment around. that mean there is 15 px space between button's text to button's wall from up and bottom

Comment: Try add the CssClass to only the <asp:Label, not the button

Comment: when I delete cssClass from other tags except lable tag, all the thing back to first figure

Comment: I think It should be  resolved by getting margin property to table tag in layout template, but it does not works...

Comment: Adding to table tag like this: table.test td { padding:3px; } The styling you can try margin as you mentioned, or specify the top/bottom padding.

Comment: greate! it is that thing I want!edit your answer, I want to mark it to Answer

Comment: no problem. I edited the answer in case others have same problem and look for solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just add the cellspacing attribute?

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" cellspacing="5">
```

Comment: I tested it now. but there is no change

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding css styling:

for example this item although this is for a button:

> `<asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" style="padding:15px;" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />`

also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wx8w7we for css classes